# getting strict-origin-when-cross-origin although i provided CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True in settings.py file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, referrer-policy

I have build my frontend using Angular and backend using django-restframwork. In my settings.py I provided `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` I run it using `python3.8 manage.py runserver 5000` but when my frontend tried to send request to it it generates error.

my angular sends request like this.

my environment file where I saved my urls

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api_url: "https://localhost:5000/op-api",
  user_login_url: "https://localhost:5000/auth/login/",
  // all_users :"https://ots.ahg.af:5000/rest-auth/login",
  user_logout_url: "https://localhost:5000/auth/logout/",
  user_register_user:"https://localhost:5000/auth/register/"

};
```

and by submitting register form I send my request like this.

```
 onCreateAccount(){ 
    this.httpService.register_user(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(resp=>{
      .......
    }, error=>{
    ......
      } else{
       ........
    });
  }
```

these are in my http service where I call using the above code.

```
user_register_user = environment.user_register_user;

 public register_user(data){
    if (data != null){
      return this.http.post(this.user_register_user ,{
        'username': data.username,
        'email' : data.email,
        'password' : data.password,
      });
    }
    
  }
```

can anyone tell me why I am getting cross-origin error and what is the problem.

I tried:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api_url: "https://ots.ahg.af:5000/op-api",
  user_login_url: "https://ots.ahg.af:5000/auth/login/",
  // all_users :"https://ots.ahg.af:5000/rest-auth/login",
  user_logout_url: "https://ots.ahg.af:5000/auth/logout/",
  user_register_user:"https://ots.ahg.af:5000/auth/register/"

};
```

ots.ahg.af is my domain name

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api_url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/op-api",
  user_login_url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login/",
  // all_users :"http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login",
  user_logout_url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/logout/",
  user_register_user:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/register/"

};
```

none of the above worked for me.

Comment: @xcvbn yes I did

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command: `python3.8 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`

Detail here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver